# Qt debugging stops on deserialize

Tags: c++, qt, deserialization, dlib

hi i'm working with dlib and I have this error about deserialize.

My exe file works fine, but it only stops when I try to debug it on my Qt creator.
It doesn't give me any error message, it just stops and does not works. I can't even press exit on my project, I can only make it stop by pressing 'stop debugging' button on Qt.

It does works when I run my exe file, so I have no idea what can be wrong. I tried to find out where the error occurs, and this is my code.

```
 if (set)
    {
        //DNN for shape predictor
        dlib::shape_predictor sp;
        qDebug("on_pushButton_clicked"); // I get this 
        dlib::deserialize("shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat") >> sp;
        qDebug("destination"); // I don't get this message 
       
        //shape detector extracts face images from image
        auto shape = sp(spimg, dets[0]);
        dlib::matrix<dlib::rgb_pixel> face_chip;
        dlib::extract_image_chip(spimg, dlib::get_face_chip_details(shape, 150, 0.25), face_chip);

        //Add face to global variable
        std_faces.push_back(std::move(face_chip));

        //send signal to open the mainwindow
        emit Photo::ClosedProperly();

        keep_sending = true;
    }
```

as I get the first qDebug message and it stops, so I suspect that in deserialize function my debugging stops for some reason. I'm keep searching about dlib and deserialize but I couldn't get satisfactory answer yet.. I'll keep looking on it, but I post this question that someone might experienced similar problem and has a clue to figure this out.

Thanks for reading this.

p.s. I think my debugging breakpoint doesn't work around that spot... this code is a part of `on_pushButton_clicked()` and it gives a qDebug message but breakpoint doesn't work. I'm not sure it's relative to the problem I have, but I add this information so it might help.

Comment: It might just be taking a long time to load the file. If you're doing a slow operation (like reading in and processing a few MB of data from disk) in a GUI callback, then the user interface will be unresponsive until the operation has completed.

Comment: Most likely that's what @vipw commented. Try instead something like `_asyncOper = std::async(std::launch::async, []() { dlib::deserialize("xxx"); emit deserializationFinished });` and connect that signal to some slot that informs about successful deserialization

Comment: welll, I've let debugging go on for about 5 hours and it still doesn't work so I doubt that it's just a long duration time... I

Comment: I think I fixed it by changing shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat file directory..!